# How to debug Xcode apps in a specific locale (English, say)?

Tags: xcode, localization

When I develop a Mac app with localized interface with Xcode, I tend to modify the English resources and have them localized/translated only when the rest of the development work is done. Being on a non-English system, when I ask Xcode to run the app, it uses the localization to my own language, when I would want to choose myself (and choose English, in most cases).

So, how do I tell Xcode what language I want the app in during debug sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for an answer for Xcode 4.X but I hope that this will help.

In Xcode 3.2.6 in the Groups & Files section of the project window open up the Executable section. Select the executable you want to run in English, and do command I. Click on the "Arguments" tab and then click on the + at the bottom. Then add:

-AppleLanguages "English"

as an argument.

hth

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It should be `-AppleLanguages "(English)"` though (notice the parentheses)…

Comment: Doesn't seem effective in Xcode 5... must be missing something on my end.

Comment: For Xcode 11, "Product" > "Scheme" > "Edit Schemes"(⌘<), in the "Arguments passed on Launch", add a row and input `-AppleLanguages "(Thai)"` or something you need, then relaunch your app from Xcode. It works for me.

Answer (score 12):

In current Xcode you can set the Application Language that you launch if you Edit the Scheme and go to the Run options.

[image: Scheme Run Options]

Comment: 6 years and this answer is still useful

Answer (score 4):

If you are debugging on iOS Simulator:

1. Run **iOS Simulator**
2. Click **Home Button**
3. Go into it's **Settings.app**
4. **General**
5. **International**
6. **Language** -> chouse English or any other

If you are debugging on Device - repeat all steps from 2) till 6).

Comment: 1. I happen to develop Mac apps, sorry it wasn't clear. I edit the question.  2. This doesn't help Xcode run in a specific locale, but simply changes my locale (which I don't want to do).